# no such directory -bash on opening terminal

Tags: terminal, rvm

-bash: /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory

This is the greeting I get each time I open terminal. Clearly this seems an important alert but as i have rvm working fine, I don't understand the problem. Any help to rid me of this message?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're giving a wrong path to the terminal. Perhaps you should edit your `.bash_profile`.

Replace

`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"`

with

`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`

Comment: It's a hidden file located in your home folder. For example, if you want to edit it via nano you'd do `nano ~/.bash_profile` or `nano /home/yourusername/.bash_profile`.